# Twitter Bootstrap - p class = well fails to include <h1> content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was playing around with twitter bootstrap. I came across a [template](http://startbootstrap.com/templates/simple-sidebar.html) which i really liked and I am using for a mini project . I made a few minor changes to the grid layout to have a 2 column structure , the code for which is below  -

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="content-header">
          <h1>
            <a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></a>
            Family Tree
          </h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Keep all page content within the page-content inset div! -->
        <div class="page-content inset">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <p class="lead">For We are now so big, we need computers to remember stuff.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <p class="well"><img src = "bootstrap/img/napa.jpg" height = "500" width = "346"> 

              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <p class="well"><h1>Nanna </h1></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Now the image in the right hand side fits perfectly (because I have specified the height and width, but if i put any text it appears outside the well. Similarly, on the left hand side the text between the `h1` tags appears outside the well, if i put in a normal text without any `header` tags, the text is within the well. I tried using `p class = "well-lg"` but there was no change. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DEMO: http://jsbin.com/iKENaGU/1/edit

Wells are divs, sections, articles, aside (or other block level elements), but you can't put an h1 inside a p, so a well is not a p.well. Check out GetBootstrap.com for instructions on Bootstrap specific stuff but also look at html5 basics too. To get a responsive image, add "img-responsive" on the img tag. .well-lg is just a padding adjustment. The wrapper for rows and columns is a .container.

```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <p class="lead">For We are now so big, we need computers to remember stuff.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="well"><img src="http://placehold.it/500x500/B7AF90/FFFFFF&text=image+1" class="img-responsive" /> 

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="well">
            <h1>Nanna </h1>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Pretty elementary mistakes there. I will have to read more . Thank a lot much